# Why do these operations not yield the same result? Piping into . (dot)

Tags: r, magrittr

I ran into something today when using `.` and `%>%` which I don't quite understand. Now I am not sure if I understand either operator.

## Data

```
set.seed(1)
df <- setDT(data.frame(id = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T), value = runif(10)))
```

#### Why are are these three equivelant

```
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% .$Mean %>% sum()
[1] 3.529399
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% {sum(.$Mean)}
[1] 3.529399
sum(df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)]$Mean)
[1] 3.529399
```

#### But this answer so different?

```
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% sum(.$Mean)
[1] 22.0588
```

Could someone explain to me how the pipe operator actually works w.r.t to `.` usage. I used to think along the lines of *Go fetch what sits on the left of the `%>%`*.

#### Investigation that left me more confused

I tried replacing the `sum` with `print` to see what was actually going on

```
# As Expected
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% .$Mean %>% print()
[1] 0.5111589 0.7698414 0.7475319 0.9919061 0.5089610
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% print(.$Mean) %>% sum()
[1] 3.529399

# Surprised
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% print(.$Mean)
    id      Mean
 1:  1 0.5111589
---             
 5:  3 0.5089610

# Same
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% sum(print(.$Mean))
[1] 22.0588

# Utterly Confused
df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% print(.$Mean) %>% sum()
[1] 18.5294 #Not even the same as above??
```

---

**Edit:** Looks like nothing to do with *data.table* or how it was grouped, same issue with *data.frame*:

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 4:6)

sum(x$x1)
# [1] 6
sum(x$x2)
# [1] 15

x %>% .$x1 %>% sum
# [1] 6
x %>% .$x2 %>% sum
# [1] 15

# Why?
x %>% sum(.$x1)
# [1] 27
x %>% sum(.$x2)
# [1] 36
```

Comment: The value of `18.5294` can be explained better then `22.0588`; it is the result of summing the complete dataset, see: `df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)] %>% unlist() %>% sum()`

Comment: on the second example `x %>% pull(x1) %>% sum()` does also give the expected result

Comment: @Jaap Yeah, pull or pre-selecting before sum works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated short example helps.

As we know when using pipes, the first argument comes from `LHS` (unless we "stop" it by `{}`) so what happens is :

```
x %>% sum(.$x1)
#[1] 27
```

is equivalent to

```
sum(x, x$x1)
#[1] 27
```

The complete sum of dataframe is added with column `x1`.

---

As far as the original example is concerned, we can verify the same behavior

```
library(data.table)

temp <- df[, .(Mean = mean(value)), by = .(id)]
sum(temp, temp$Mean)
#[1] 22.0588
```

Comment: Thanks, `sum(x, x$x1)` makes sense now especially in the context of the function needing its first argument `f(x, ...)` specified.